# MySQL Foreign keys: should i set it up?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

Do i need to setting the foreign key for this situation ?
i'm weak in database design, especially in mysql.. may i know if i want to setting foreign keys for them, what should i setting for them ? in case if the people delete... all referral to people_id will delete together, is it possible to set while the table is too many ?
Thx for reply

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Foreign key constraints enforce referential integrity, a key tenet of ensuring that your data is reliable and of high quality.  Otherwise, your people_address table could reference a people_id value that doesn't exist in the people table, and would be an orphan.  A foreign key constraint would prevent that from happening.

So, just do it.  There's really no good reason not to.

Define foreign keys such as the following on the people_email table:

ALTER TABLE people_email ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (people_id) REFERENCES people (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

This will mean that you cannot enter a record in people_email where the people_id in that table does not exist in people.  Also, if you delete the parent row in people, the rows referencing it in people_email with get automatically deleted.

I personally prefer to manually delete all the rows from the child tables and not use cascade deletes though.  It's a bit of extra app dev work, but it makes me feel safer and also allows me some control over locking and ensuring that queries are as efficient as possible.

Comment: may i know what should i setting for it ? eg. make people_id in people_address as primary, then link foreign key to db.people.id and cascade as update and delete ? i want the address will get delete when people delete. when people update people will not affect address except people is editing address...